# "meta temporarily unavailable" on election nomination

Tags: support, election, meta

On [StrixVaria's nomination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-151628) I'm seeing "meta temporarily unavailable" in the stats section, right above the count of helpful flags.  This is the only nomination where I see this error, the others all list the meta questions/answers.  From taking a glance at his meta profile I can't see any reason why the stats wouldn't be available or anything else wrong.  What's happening here?